# rubber seals in unheated shed over winter have broken down,

Tags: hose

I hooked up my hose for the first time this spring, intending to water some of my garden. The first nozzle was a wand style and was leaking horrendously at trigger area. I then switched to a gun style nozzle and it was leaking even worse, every orafice was spraying water. Both these items were stored in an unheated shed over the winter. Am I looking at a weird coincidence? I've never stored any of my hoses or nozzles indoors but the items in question were just purchased last summer. Has something changed in the rubber formulas they use these days?

Answer (score -2):

The water in the attachments froze over the winter and broke the valve bodies.  thats why they are leaking now.  next year, take them and your hoses inside before freeze up.

Comment: or drain everything